# Why does this happen when we override the ToString() method in a class?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, class, overriding

I created a Person class and overrode some properties and constructor method and override ToString() method.

[image]

And I defined another class MyClass<T1> generically and created a field called a and the constructor method and the print method of field a.

[image]

And inside the main method, I created a new object of the Person class called class1 and filled the properties related to the Person class and called the print method through the class1 object.

[image]

And I am given the below output.

[image]

Why did this happen?

I know it's because of overriding ToString() but I don't understand it. :(

Comment: Why did *what* happen? And what do you mean by "why"? What did you expect instead?

Comment: Please post code as text, not as images.

Comment: @Sweeper, I didn't expect otherwise, but I don't understand the process, it's confusing

Comment: Your code is correct. You only need to know that when you call `Print`, `ToString()` is called.

Comment: What's confusing about it? You are creating a `string` that contains a representation of your object. How else would you expect that to be created other than calling its `ToString` method? That method exists specifically to create a `string` representation of an instance of that class. That's what you're doing so that's the method that gets called. What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ToString()` method is called by `MyClass<T>.Print()` when it is calling `Console.WriteLine`.
You pass your `Person` into Console.WriteLine as parameter for a call to format and print string (do you see `{0}` placeholder in Console.WriteLine first argument?). Inside it calls `string.Format` to render the string and this is the place where your overriden `ToString()` implementation is called.

You can set a breakpoint inside `ToString()` method, run the debugger and look through the callstack, to find actual callers of your method.